# FIWARE Orion Context Broker subscription to several points

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I'm using Orion with Keyrock, PEPproxy, Cygnus and STH-comet, but I'm having many issues with the subscriptions part. I want to  send only one request to orion to subscribe all atributes of all entities in many services like Cygnus and STH. I'm using this body but I don't know how to add other notification URL.

```
{  
  "subject":{
    "entities": [
        {
           "type": "Nodo_aire",
            "idPattern": ".*"
        }
    ],
    "condition":{
    "attrs": []      
    }
  },
  "notification":{
    "http":{"url":"http://192.168.1.51:5050/notify"},
    "attrs": [],
    "attrsFormat":"legacy"
  },
  "expires": "2099-12-31T23:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 5
}
```

I was reading the Orion documentation and the NGSIv2, but i dont find a related section or a solution in these documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion doesn't support (at least in the newest version) multi-URL subscriptions. However, there is an easy workaround: to implement a subscription for each one of the URLs.